# Java Boolean return statement

Tags: java, boolean, return

I'm trying to write a program that will print out a failure message if the file index doesn't exist. When I put this code into BlueJ it tells me I need a return statement. help?

```
public boolean validIndex(int index)
    {
        if ((index >= 0) && (index <= files.size() - 1)) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("File not found.");
        }
    }
```

Comment: All code paths must return something, you should be returning false after (instead of?) printing.

Answer (score 0):

In your else statement it should be, "return false".

If you were doing a - public String validIndex(int index)
 You could return the message your trying to output which is: 
System.out.println("File not found.");

Answer (score 0):

You have not added return l for else statement. Either add a return out of the if else statement or in the else statement

```
public boolean validIndex(int index) {
 if ((index >= 0) && (index <= files.size() - 1)) {
 return true; 
} else {
 System.out.println("File not found.");
 }
return false; 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should return something in the `else`. You have specified return type as boolean so the method should always return a `boolean`.

```
public boolean validIndex(int index)
{
        if ((index >= 0) && (index <= files.size() - 1)) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("File not found.");
            return false;
        }
}
```